# Por qué me está dando este error

Tags: javascript

Cada vez que intento agregar un if dentro la función de *oninput* me da error como si no existiera la variable del *for* mientras si no pongo if si me ejecuta cualquier cosa que meta dentro de esa función siempre y cuando no llame esa variable *input_code* qué estoy haciendo mal?

```js
login_button = function() {

   // INSTRUCCIONES PRIMARIAS
   //if (){} SI SE CUMPLE EL IF EL SETTIMEOUT SE EJECUTA
   setTimeout(function(){

      var input_code = document.querySelectorAll(".identified-input-code > input");

      for (var i = 0; i < input_code.length; i++) {

          input_code[i].oninput = function () {
                    
              if (input_code[i].value.length > 0) {
                     document.write("Si");
              } // CUANDO PONGO ESTE IF ME DA ERROR MIENTRAS SI 
   //DEJO SOLO LA FUNCIÓN DE ONINPUT ME EJECUTA LO QUE META DENTRO
   // ERRORES:
   // ONCLICK
   // INPUT
   //setTimeout handler*login_button.onclick 
   // login_button es el botón principal de toda la función
   //EventHandlerNonNull*
          }
      }
   }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Y cuál es el error?

Comment: ¿Qué es "cualquier cosa"? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo?

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez document.write, alert() etc... menos cosas donde se llame el input_code[0]

Comment: Es un poco confuso, ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer?, por cierto no se si eso querías hacer o no pero la comparación de "input_code[i].value.length"  la puedes sustituir por "input_code[i].value" si solo deseas los valores, aunque repito no se que quieres hacer, puede que este mal.

Comment: te falta un ) en la penultima }

Comment: Ya descubrí qué pasó, básicamente había que repetir el ciclo for dentro de la función oninput con la misma variable si se quiere, ya que el for principal pues tiene la variable i que es local, entonces al intentar llamarla dentro de una función en este caso el oninput va a dar error si no se crea otro ciclo for.

Comment: corrígeme si me equivoco, estas iterando un nodo en busca de hijos, estos hijos son los inputs y estas agregando un oyente a esos inputs para poder manejar la lógica una vez haya un dato dentro del input ? si esto es así yo te recomiendo que pases tu código a una forma mas declarativa